# Eclipse (CDT - DSF) Debug View Plugin / Extension

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, debugging, view, eclipse-cdt

I am starting to get into Eclipse plugin development and I want to develop an extension or plugin for the eclipse CDT debug view. Actually, I want to see if its possible to do what I want. I have spent a good amount of time researching without finding anything.

I am using CDT and basically I want to extend the Eclipse debug view to be able to view different threads in a specific way for a proprietary OS. Essentially I have a plugin that would be talking to a GDB server sending commands to GDB. The commands to GDB would be causing changes to the program counter, stack pointer, and possibly some other important CPU registers. When the program counter or stack pointer changes, I need the register and debug views to update with the new stack frame information.

It seems as though there was a thread of a team doing exactly what I want to achieve here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.cdt.devel/20936. However the thread seems to have gone into the ether. The poster on that thread wanted to use the DSF dispatch event method with a state changed event to cause an update to all the debug views in the session.

My main question is: Does anybody have any clue if there is a solid way to cause the debug views to update after I go and change some registers through GDB? It is wholly unclear whether or not the state changed event would work as actual comprehensive DSF documentation does not appear to have materialized.

Comment: This Q is very broad. Start with https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf.gdb and http://help.eclipse.org/neon/nftopic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dsf/intro/dsf_programming_intro.html?cp=12_0_5 to get started on DSF in CDT. The example project shows overriding the terminate, but other things can be overridden the same sort of way.